# How to concatenate null columns in spark dataframe in java?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

I am working with spark in java and I want to create a column which is a concatenation of all other column values separated by comma. I have tried few ways to do this but couldn't find a solution.

For example-

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | result
 1   | john | 2.3  | 1,john,2.3
```

***The problem that I'm facing is if a column value is null then simply nothing should be there but so far I have not achieved this.***

For example-

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | result
 1   | null | 2.3  | 1,,2.3  -> this is what I'm trying to achieve
```

**What I have tried**-

1.) I tried concat function of spark sql but if a column value is null then entire value of concat function will be null, which is not something i want.

2.) concat_ws function simply ignore the null values hence can't be used. Hence in my 2nd example the result would be something like `1,2.3`

3.) using coalesce require matching data types so if I do something like coalesce(col_name,'') under concat function and col_name is number data type then it throws data types mismatch error.

4.) using case when statement also require same data type in THEN & ELSE conditions. So if I say `case when column_1 is null THEN '' ELSE column1 END` will throw error if column1 is number because '' is empty string and column_1 is number.

one way it can be achieved is creating map_function. But is there a way to do it in spark sql way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast all your fields to `String` so that you can run `NVL` on them and set them to empty string `''` if they're null.

To generate an expression for all the columns in your dataframe automatically, you can use `map` function:

```java
df.show()
//+----+----+----+
//|col1|col2|col3|
//+----+----+----+
//|   1|John| 2.3|
//|   2|null| 2.3|
//+----+----+----+


List<String> columns = df.columns() ; 
// List("col1", "col2", "col3")

String nvlExpr = columns.stream().map(i -> "nvl(cast ("+i+" as string),'')").collect(joining(", ", "concat_ws(','," , ")"));

//concat_ws(',',nvl(cast (col1 as string), ''), nvl(cast (col2 as string), ''),nvl(cast (col3 as string), ''))

df.withColumn("result", expr(nvlExpr)).show()

//+----+----+----+----------+
//|col1|col2|col3|    result|
//+----+----+----+----------+
//|   1|John| 2.3|1,John,2.3|
//|   2|null| 2.3|    2,,2.3|
//+----+----+----+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly what I expected. Taking it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can concat

```html
scala> spark.sql("select *, concat(cast(col1 as string),',' ,col2,',' ,cast(col3 as string)) as result from (select col1, col3, case when col2 is null then '' else col2 end as col2 from final)").show()
+----+----+----+--------+
|col1|col3|col2|  result|
+----+----+----+--------+
|   1| 2.3|  JK|1,JK,2.3|
|   1| 2.3|    |  1,,2.3|
+----+----+----+--------+
```